# flutter bloc streambuilder with refreshindicator rebuild twice

Tags: flutter

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final blocData = WeatherBlocProvider.of(context).bloc;
    if (WeatherBloc.permission == true) {
      blocData.forceRefreshAll();
      return Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: blocData.zipAll,
            builder: (scontext, snapshot){
                //to do
               }
```

now i am using bloc pattern with streambuilder
and when i refresh parent widget i can see `blocData.forceRefreshAll()` this line is requested twice.(i mean build method is requested twice) how can i make only one?
i saw `unwanted rebuild subject` and they said use instance or initstate but with bloc pattern i think using initstate is not possible and const value is not working with 
 `blocData.forceRefreshAll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build` method is meant to build widget tree, it can be called multiple times for various reasons. This is why should not fetch data in `build`.
If you can't access bloc in `initState` because there is no `context` yet - override another method, `didChangeDependencies`. It's called right after `initState` and it can use `context`, so you can access bloc provider with it.

Comment: thanks for quick answer but when i refresh didchagedependencies is also called twice

Comment: yes, it can be called multiple times too, so if you want to ensure your method is called once you can create some flag (`bool isDataRequested` for example) and fetch data only if flag is not set

Comment: thanks i think i solve the problem and could i ask why refreshindicator works twice?

Comment: It's hard to tell having a small part of code, so answer will be abstract. It happens because something changes in widget tree and framework decides to rebuild it. Also StreamBuilder can cause such behaviour, 1st time it fires without data and then it catches up data from stream